# Magento url redirect problem ... Admin is not opening

Tags: admin, url, redirect

I wanted to redirect my website now www to www ... lookied into some help and then went and made fallowing changes

System > Configuration menu and from the left panel click the "Web" button.

Unfold the "Unsecured" set of options and change the "Base URL" option from http://yourdomain.com to http://www.yourdomain.com.

after that non of my pages are openning ... infact admin is also not opening as its getting redirected ....

Please help ...

Answer (score 3):

Check if there is a rewrite rule redirecting www.yourdomain.com to yourdomain.com in your web server config EA .htaccess for Apache. If so, once you change base_url to http://www.yourdomain.com, your browser will get looping and non of your pages can be opened.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your

> database/phpmyadmin

Find table `core_config_data`

Go to row with path = `web/unsecure/base_url`

Change its value to whatever it was when running properly.

It always ends with a `/`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change both the **unsecure** and **secure** urls to get it changed.
and as TBI Infotech said the url always ends with a "/". So your new url will be "http://www.yourdomain.com/" for both secure and unsecure section.